# can I provide datasource with RESOURCE_LOCAL persistence unit?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

When I hava a persistence unit which has transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" can I somehow provide datasource (created by my application) - instead of providing javax.persistence.jdbc.url, user, password, driver etc?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Just create it and put inside application context.

On java site, before you create EntityManagerFactory:

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();

    BasicDataSource bs = new BasicDataSource(); //that is DataSource implementation from apache commons-dbcp
    bs.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    ...
    initCtx.bind("MY_DATA_SOURCE", bs);
```

And in your persistence.xml

```
  <persistence-unit name="YourPersistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>MY_DATA_SOURCE</non-jta-data-source>
    ....
```